Location of, or how to view downloaded Telegram files
I have an Infinix Note 12 (X670) running Android 13. Starting a few weeks ago, I could no longer see downloaded files in the /data/org.telegram.messenger/files directory.
Where are downloaded files from Telegram being saved? Or, how can I view them again?

Check Telegram folder in storage/emulated/0/Downloads in other words in your download folder using any file explorer//That's where I see on my Pixel. I don't think it should be different on your Infinix but then...

I use Telegram from it's site not Play Store. IDK if that matters

No, the downloaded files are not in the Download folder, the search continues, I shall update here if I find anything new

They are in Android/data/, and Google recently made our devices more secure by removing access to that folder. Even with root, it's only through the Files app and not the latest because it was already patched. I'm using 6.1 if I need to move in/out/edit anything in there.

Welcome, and thanks for posting an answer. If you have a follow-up question, then please post it as a new question. You can link this question for additional context. Thanks for your understanding.
